# Stuck on black screen log when trying to boot into linux

Tags: linux, boot, system-installation

I'm trying to install Linux on to my computer. The distribution I'm currently trying to install is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS but I've had the same issue when trying to install Kali and older versions of Ubuntu. I already had Ubuntu installed on this system about half a year ago but then swapped to Windows 11. The installation was without issues in the past with the same installation media.

The issue arises as I am trying to boot into Linux for the first time when trying to install it.

Here is the log I get written out on black screen:

```
[   4.911917] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
[   4.911920] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
[   4.911923] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
[   4.911926] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
[   4.911929] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 12 on hub 0
[   4.911932] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring kiq_2.1.0 uses VM inv eng 13 on hub 0
[   4.911935] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 1
[   4.911938] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_dec uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 1
[   4.911941] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 1
[   4.911944] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc1 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 1
[   4.911947] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 1
[   4.913226] [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.49.0 20150101 for 0000:04:00.0 on minor 1
[   4.920942] fbcon: amdgpudrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   4.921288] [drm] DSC precompute is not needed.
[   4.924335] input: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. N-KEY Device as devices/pc10000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:04:00.3/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.2/0003:0B05:1866.0007/input/input21
[   4.970442] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[   4.981432] asus 0003:0B05:1866.0007: input,hiddev2,hidraw6: USB HID v1.10 Device [ASUSTeK Computer Inc. N-KEY Device] on usb-0000:04:00.3-3/input2
[   4.988637] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: [drm] fb0: amdgpudrmfb frame buffer device
```

I think the issue has to do with the installation media (USB) but if possible I would like to fix the issue so I will be able to boot from this installation media without switching it.

Thank you in advance!

Edit: I've tried to install Kali through a different installation media but get the same result.

Comment: So you don't think the inability to switch from text console into graphics mode could have anything to do with your GPU (which is what almost all the lines in the log you supplied talk about)? Maybe try to disable it temporarily?

Comment: I tried disabling both AMD Radeon(TM) Graphics and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti from my device but it didn't change anything. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same issue and messages. Anyone know a fix? I can run Kali on a VM with this laptop but I am not able to get dual boot or kali to load directly on the hardware. My UEFI wont let me disable the GPU.